# How can i use SetLocaleinfo()

Tags: c#

I want to change the language of OS using C#. so how to use SetLocaleinfo() function in c#

Comment: What do you mean by change language, can you provide examples of the outcomes you have in mind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice, if you would provide more information about your environment (e.g. the UI you use winforms/wpf/silverlight/...), to get a more specific answere.

If you use WPF or Silverlight, try:

```
// Put the using statements at the beginning of the code module
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
// Put the following code before InitializeComponent()
// Sets the culture to French (France)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
// Sets the UI culture to French (France)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```